# nodemailer && mailtrap -> connect ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: node.js, next.js, smtp, nodemailer, mailtrap

I'm Working on a Dummy Project in **nextjs** and trying to send a reset password message to the user email using **mailtrap** and **nodemailer** but i have a problem I can't find any solution for it when I send the request this error happen

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 18.215.44.90:2525
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '18.215.44.90',
  port: 2525,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

and **Here's my code**

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

async function SendEmail(options) {
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
        port: 2525,
        auth: {
            user: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        },
    });

    const message = {
        from: `${process.env.SMTP_FROM_NAME} <${process.env.SMTP_FROM_EMAIL}>`,
        to: options.email,
        subject: options.subject,
        text: options.message,
    };

    await transport.sendMail(message, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
        }
    });
}

export default SendEmail;
```

Comment: Remove await from transport.sendMail, there's no need to await it if you are providing callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing the port, another solution is to try it on another internet network, sometimes in some way, the ip provided by the provider has been blocked, that same error happened to me and my solution was to change the internet network.

Comment: I was stuck from 2 days in this error and final this answer really helped me. Thank you soo much for your kind sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using school/college wlan/wifi, try using your phone hotspot. Maybe School/College connection is blocking the port.